# is it possible to create a method that returns the count of bools which = true?

Tags: dart, countif

total amateur here! I am working on a bingo app where i have a 4 x 4 grid. Each row and each column has a bool property which indicates whether it's a completed line or not. So..

```
bool row1 = false,
bool row2 = false,
bool row3 = false,
bool row4 = false,
bool column1 = false,
bool column2 = false,
bool column3 = false,
bool column4 = false
```

If the user completes a row the property changes to 'true' - I've worked that bit out.

Now i want a 'completedRows' property which provides the count of rows that = true (and same for columns)

Is it possible to create a function that does this?

Comment: You probably should use a [`lList`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists) for that, instead of single variables. Currently the only way to count count completed rows is to look at each variable separately.

Answer (score 0):

Not convenient, but definitely possible:

```dart
int get completedRowCount =>
  (row1 ? 1 : 0) + (row2 ? 1 : 0) + (row3 ? 1 : 0) + (row4 ? 1 : 0);
```

Since you are using individual variables, you have to access those variables independently.
You could do something like:

```dart
int get completedRowCount =>
  [row1, row2, row3, row4].where((b) => b).length;
```

but that's not any more general than the code above, and more wasteful in memory use.

If instead of using individual variables, you used lists of booleans, then you can more easily generalize to, say, more rows or columns.

Say, you had

```dart
List<bool> row = List.filled(4, false);
List<bool> column = List.filled(4, false);
```

then instead of `row1 = true;` you write `row[1] = true;`,
but you can then use:

```dart
int get completedRowCount => row.where((b) => b).length;
```

to get the completed count. Or:

```dart
int get completedRowCount {
  var count = 0;
  for (var value in row) {
    if (value) count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

I'd probably wrap everything up in a class, that would allow you to abstract over the row and column count. Something like:

```dart
class BingoGrid {
  final List<bool> completedRows;
  final List<bool> completedColumns;
  // Other properties.
  BingoGrid(int columns, int rows) 
      : completedRows = List<bool>.filled(rows, false),
        completedColumns = List<bool>.filled(columns, false);
  // ...
  static bool _isTrue(bool b) => b;
  int get completedRowCount => completedRows.where(_isTrue).length;
  int get completedColumnCount => completedColumns.where(_isTrue).length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much :) - it's going to take me some time to work through this and properly understand the concepts but looks like a comprehensive response. Thanks for taking the time